# How to get list of uncommitted files from SharpSVN

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

Using SharpSvn, how can I get a list of files that need to be committed (the list that you would see if you right click on a folder with tortoisesvn and hit commit)

I tried this:

```
        SharpSvn.SvnClient client = new SharpSvn.SvnClient();
        Collection<SvnListChangeListEventArgs> list;
        bool result = client.GetChangeList(@"C:\MyProjectPath", out list);
```

But it seems to be returning a list of every file in the project instead of just the modified ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're using is for the [changelist feature](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.changelists.html). To see what files are changed use the [`GetStatus` or `Status`](http://sharpsvntips.net/post/1312684793/getstatus-and-status) calls. In this case you want to check the `LocalContentStatus` and `LocalPropertyStatus`

Answer (score 3):

Sander is correct, here is a more complete example of listing modified files:

```
var statusArgs = new SvnStatusArgs();
statusArgs.Depth = SvnDepth.Infinity;
statusArgs.RetrieveAllEntries = true;
Collection<SvnStatusEventArgs> statuses;
svnClient.GetStatus(@"C:\SVN\stuff\", statusArgs, out statuses);
foreach (SvnStatusEventArgs statusEventArgs in statuses)
{
   if (statusEventArgs.LocalContentStatus == SvnStatus.Modified)
      Console.WriteLine("Modified file: " + statusEventArgs.Path);
}
```